# How to Implement "seen" in my website

Tags: php, session-cookies

In my website which I am developing I want to implement stackoverflow's userprofile  "seen" in visits section  which says when we were last seen.This is giving me the date.But I want like "2h ago".How to do that?
I tried this:

```
    <?php 
     if(isset($_COOKIE['AboutVisit'])) 
  { 
     $last = $_COOKIE['AboutVisit']; 
  } 


     setcookie(AboutVisit, time ()) ; 
     if (isset ($last)) 
     { 
     $change = time () - $last; 
     if ( $change > 60)
     { 
     echo "Welcome back! <br> You last visited on ". date("m/d/y",$last) ; 
     // Tells the user when they last visited 
     } 

     else 
     { 
     echo "Welcome to our site!"; 
     //Greets a first time user 
     } 
}
 ?>
```

Comment: just store the time stamp of last visit and then subtract it from current time stamp. and covert it using `"last seen ".date('H',$timestamp)." hours ago"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function below will calculate the time span between start and end date. You can modify it to format the timespan as per your wish:

```
/**
     * Calculates the timespan between the start and end datetime
     * @param timestamp $start The start timestamp for the time span
     * @param timestamp $end The end timestamp for the time span
     * @return string A string with the matched timespan
     */
    public function timespan( $start, $end )
    {
        $seconds = $end - $start;
        $days = floor( $seconds / 60 / 60 / 24 );
        $hours = $seconds / 60 / 60 % 24;
        $mins = $seconds / 60 % 60;
        $secs = $seconds % 60;

        $duration = "";
        if ( $days > 0 )
        {
            $hr = ($hours > 1) ? " $hours hours" : (($hours > 0) ? " $hours hour" : "");
            $duration .= ($days > 1) ? "$days days$hr ago" : "$days day$hr ago";
        }
        elseif ( $hours > 0 )
        {
            $mi = ($mins > 1) ? " $mins minutes" : (($mins > 0) ? " $mins minute" : "");
            $duration .= ($hours > 1) ? "$hours hours$mi ago" : "$hours hour$mi ago";
        }
        elseif ( $mins > 0 )
        {
            $duration .= ($mins > 1) ? "$mins minutes ago" : "$mins minute ago";
        }
        elseif ( $secs > 0 )
        {
            $duration .= ($secs > 1) ? "$secs seconds ago" : "$secs second ago";
        }

        $duration = trim( $duration );
        if ( $duration == null )
            $duration = '0 seconds ago';

        return $duration;
    }
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Simply make the use of the timestamp on the login cookie.  If the user has logged in for the first time, the cookie would not be present earlier and hence you can give 'Welcome to our site!' otherwise stamp date and time on the login cookie whenever the user logs in and then use that value to display "last seen" time.